# How to customize Jquery Data table page navigation?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to implement page navigation in following way, is there any way to customize the same. I am new to Jquery Data table. Please help me.

Required page navigation

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10...

if user clicks on ... it will show
 ... 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20...

in second page navigation row (...) would appear on both side, so that user can move to next/ previous page of navigation row.

can this be achievable in JQuery data table. Please suggest?
 Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

DataTables supports 5 default paging types, found [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType). These types are

> - `numbers` -Page number buttons only
> - `simple` -'Previous' and 'Next' buttons only
> - `simple_numbers` -'Previous' and 'Next' buttons, plus page numbers
> - `full` -'First', 'Previous', 'Next', and 'Last' buttons
> - `full_numbers` -'First', 'Previous', 'Next', and 'Last' buttons, plus page numbers

Unfortunately, none of these options outlines the type of paging you want. If you *really* want to have that form of pagination, you'll have to write your own custom JS to handle the paging and then use the DataTables `page()` [API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page()) to allow it to interact with DataTables.